# Comparing one list with list of list and replace values

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list x which looks like this

```
[[3,6,7,8],
[2,4,5,7],
[4,5,8,10]]
```

and i have another list with 10 elements

```
y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

i want to update x based on y so that it look like

```
[[0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
[0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1]]
```

my code looks like this

```
newlst3=[]
for x in range(10):
    newlst3.append(0)

for x in newlst:
    newlst3[x]=1
```

my code only does it for a single list but not for a list of lists

Comment: sorry! i edit it

Comment: is y actually important or this is just a range of 0 to the max of the list of lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = [[3, 6, 7, 8], [2, 4, 5, 7], [4, 5, 8, 10]]
y = list(range(1, 11))

output = []
for sublist in x:
    output.append([1 if i in sublist else 0 for i in y])
```

Comment: Question was initially tagged `pandas` so I jumped into `numpy`, but this might make more sense ;)

Comment: Btw, you can make it much simpler: `[[1 if i in x2 else 0 for i in range(10)] for x2 in x ]`, but +1 for @Jacob

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the values in the first lists as indexes to set 1s in the final output. You can use a bit of numpy:

input:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[3,6,7,8],
              [2,4,5,7],
              [4,5,8,10]])
```

processing:

```
out = np.zeros((x.shape[0], x.max()))
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    out[i,x[i]-1]=1
```

output:

```
array([[0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Double loop to iterate the elements of both lists and check for their presence.

```
ListX = [[3, 6, 7, 8], [2, 4, 5, 7], [4, 5, 8, 10]]
ListY = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
output = []

for element in ListX:

    list = []
    for index in ListY:

        if index in element:
            list.append(1)
        else:
            list.append(0)

    output.append(list)
```

OUTPUT

```
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
```